# Significance of Man with a piece missing cake in Shape of Water

Tags: analysis, the-shape-of-water

At the beginning of [*The Shape of Water*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shape_of_Water_(film)) when Elisa is going to her work, at the bus stop there was a man sitting there with a cake (looked like a birthday cake) and we can clearly see that a piece from the cake is missing like it is cut for eating.

What is the significance of this scene?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of the scene referred to in the question:

[image: The Shape of Water - birthday boy at the bus stop]

Veteran actor Richard Jenkins, who plays Giles, the gay best friend and neighbor of Elisa Esposito (Sally Hawkins), explains this [in an interview with *Washington Blade*](http://www.washingtonblade.com/2017/12/14/actor-richard-jenkins-plays-gay-shape-water/) :

> The seasoned actor is also full of admiration for writer/director
>   Guillermo Del Toro.
>
> “He is amazing, like no one else,” Jenkins says. “He’s really smart. I
>   don’t think there’s a movie he hasn’t seen and he understands what the
>   movies are about. He understands how to speak in film language.
>   Nothing is wasted in his movies. When you see a scene, everything has
>   a purpose, everything has a reason.”
>
> He cites one scene where Sally is waiting for a bus and sees a guy
>   with balloons and a birthday cake with one piece missing. **The director
>   said it was the character’s birthday party but he was the only person
>   there.** Those few seconds of film, barely noticed by most viewers,
>   expand Del Toro’s visual palette and **expand the movie’s theme of
>   lonely people trying to make connections**.

The director talked about it himself in [an interview with *The Sunday Times*](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/guillermo-del-toro-interview-oscar-nomination-best-picture-the-shape-of-water-3dqplgh65), but it is behind a paywall:

> My favourite intricacy is a man crying at a bus stop, holding a
>   birthday cake.
>
> “That is a vignette,” del Toro says, pleased it was spotted. **“This guy
>   threw a party nobody went to, and now he's going home with one slice
>   of cake cut out. He ate it, and he's bringing all the balloons home,
>   too. I was trying to show that Elisa's not lonely. She's very happy.
>   This other guy is lonely.”**